# django - Best way to compare two models?

Tags: python, django

I have a templatetag that returns all related objects through their tags, but I want to exclude *self* if the queryset looks through the same model

```
def get_related_projects(obj):
    published_projects = Project.objects.published()

    first_obj = published_projects.first()
    if first_obj.__class__ == obj.__class__:
        published_projects = published_projects.exclude(pk=obj.pk)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to compare two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type` to get the model classes and then use `is` to do a quick check on the *sameness* of the model classes:

```
if type(first_obj) is type(obj):
     published_projects = published_projects.exclude(pk=obj.pk)
```

Comment: Looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or do:

```
if isinstance(first_obj, class):
    published_projects = published_projects.exclude(pk=obj.pk)
```

If you just want to know the model class associated with a QuerySet simply do:

```
def get_related_projects(obj):
    published_projects = Project.objects.published()

    if isinstance(published_projects.model, ModelClassHere):
        published_projects = published_projects.exclude(pk=obj.pk)
```

Comment: Manually comparing a model kind of defeats the purpose, which is to compare two classes from two objects that might belong to the same class. The `published_projects.model` seems better than comparing its first object, though!

Comment: OK, so @moses answer is the most pythonic one. `is` is the one your are looking for.

Comment: Actually you had a good nugget of knowledge. Instead of retrieving the first object to get its type I just compared `published_projects.model`, so `if published_projects.model is type(obj)` also looks great